# Get all rows based on condition from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables.

1. `AccountInCompany`
2. `Account`
   `Id` | `Name`
3. `Company`

Backstory: The accounts can be part of multiple companies at the same time. And that's the purpose of `AccountInCompany`, to keep track of it.

What I want to do is get all accounts who don't are not part of any enabled companies. I tried so many different queries and I couldn't get it to work. For example:

AccountInCompany:

| `Id` | `AccountId` | `CompanyId` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | 4 |

Company:

| `Id` | `IsEnabled` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'True' |
| 2 | 'True' |
| 3 | 'False' |
| 4 | 'False' |
| 5 | 'False' |

What it means in this case: the account (`1`) should NOT be selected, because even though company (`3`) is not enabled, he is still part of companies (`1` and `2`) which are enabled. Account `2` should be skipped as well, because the company he's part of (`1`) is enabled. Account `3` should be selected because its only company (`4`) is disabled. Also account `4` should be selected because both its companies `3` and `4` are also disabled.

Some of my tries include:

```
WITH OnlyDisabled AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT u.Id
        FROM AccountInCompany ac
       INNER JOIN Account a
          ON a.Id = ac.AccountId
       INNER JOIN Company c
          ON c.Id = ac.CompanyId
       WHERE c.IsEnabled = 'False'),
    FinalList AS (
  SELECT du.Id
        FROM OnlyDisabled du
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AccountInCompany ac
       INNER JOIN Account a
          ON a.Id = ac.AccountId
       INNER JOIN Company c
          ON c.Id = ac.CompanyId
       WHERE a.IsEnabled = 'True'
         AND ac.AccountId IN (SELECT * FROM OnlyDisabled)))
SELECT * FROM FinalList;
```

Another using `ALL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.Id
        FROM AccountInCompany ac
       INNER JOIN Account a
          ON a.Id = ac.AccountId
       INNER JOIN Company c
          ON c.Id = ac.CompanyId
       WHERE c.IsEnabled = ALL (SELECT IsEnabled FROM Company WHERE IsEnabled = 'True')
```

Also tried to make it work with `GROUP BY`, but no luck either. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We connect the tables, group by `account` and then dismiss any accounts with `status = 'true'`

```
select   account
from     AccountInCompany aic 
join     Company c on c.company = aic.company
group by account
having   max(status) <> 'True'
```

| account |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dmN5Cb_X?hide=4)